# Reverse compiling with swfmill returns different result

Tags: xml, flash, reverse-engineering, swfmill

I have this very simple SWF file http://www.2shared.com/document/OgYwRBR6/test2.html and I simply converted it with swfmill into and xml.

This is the result: http://pastebin.com/UgvfeYT6

Unfortunately the reverse (compiling the xml with swfmill) returns an odd result that can be seen here http://www.2shared.com/document/4Zwd1Ggn/complex.html

I am not asking for debugging but does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

For creating the files above I use the fallowing code in console:

`swfmill swf2xml demo.swf demo.xml` - to create the xml

`swfmill simple demo.xml demo2.swf` - to recreate the swf

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
swfmill swf2xml demo.swf demo.xml
swfmill xml2swf demo.xml demo2.swf
```

`swfmill simple` allows you to compile SWFs from a simpler XML dialect that is easier to write by hand. The “simple” dialect is quite a bit different than the full dialect, although it is possible to mix the two to some extent if you know what you’re doing, which is why you get something close to what you intended.

It’s an understandable mistake, swfmill’s documentation is fairly atrocious. That’s largely my fault — sorry about that!